# What does 一話部 mean?

Tags: word-usage, parsing

This [paper](http://ypir.lib.yamaguchi-u.ac.jp/bg/metadata/1055) discusses how どうも is used. On page 216, the following sentence shows up.

> 「どうも」は、これらの文表現において、一話部をになっている。

文表現 here refers to the expressions, "Thank You" "Sorry" "Excuse Me" "thank you for coming" "sorry to take your time" "Hello" and "Goodbye". I am having a hard time figuring out what 一話部 means. I'm guessing it means "part of a sentence", but am not sure.

Does 一話部をになっている mean that the word どうも is a part of those sentences in Japanese? Or simply that it carries the meaning of some of those expressions?

Comment: Is をに intentional?

Comment: @JimmyYang the verb is 担う not なる

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's `一` "one; certain" followed by `話部` "speech (fragment); a part of spoken sentence; phrase". 話部 is a rare word, but I don't think there is a meaning more profound than what the kanji suggest. This 一話部をになっている should mean どうも functions as a part of a longer sentence (rather than functioning as a single-word sentence like "Hello!" or "Thanks!").